# Show when user is online/offline in real time on user_profile.php

Tags: php, functions

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
   <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/online.png" width="9px"style="
    margin-left: 14px;"></img><font color="#89E130"> Online</font>
<?php else: ?> 
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/offline.gif" width="9px"style="
    margin-left: 14px;"></img><font color="#878787"> Offline</font>
<?php endif ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: This doesnt work, I need to display online/offline staus on user_profile page can you provide me a code that will give me the effect

Comment: You can use [WP-UserOnline](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/) plugin for this task. You can call its shortcode wherever you need it. SHORTCODE: `[page_useronline]`. See [install instructions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/installation/) for more.

Comment: Where are you placing this code? Do you want to show this information to the user to let them know if they are logged in, or do you want the admin to be able to tell whether a user is logged in or not?

Comment: i want users to know when another user is online.. its for my freelance website. example https://www.dropbox.com/s/lifcq06y54jol7z/Screenshot%20of%20error.png?dl=0

Comment: view this solution http://allinonescript.com/questions/29641888/how-can-i-show-user-online-or-offline-from-its-session-in-php-mysql-and-ajax